# Cucumber, examples: How can I verify that the value is exact the same as that of in the adjacent column

Tags: selenium, cucumber

On the website there are 2 columns...

In my testcase in Selenium, in the examples the values are:

```
Examples:
| userrol  | information 1 | information 2 |
| role 1   | test          | rest          | 
| role 2   | test2         | rest2         |
```

Now I can test if those values are presented on the website. 
but how can I verify that rest2 is the neighbour of test2 ?

and not like this on the website:

```
| USER     | information1  | information2  |
| role 1   | test          | rest2         | 
| role 2   | test2         | rest          |
```

(It should not only test if it is presented, it should also test that the text in the column next to it is corresponding)

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: you can consider using galen framework to check the layout of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a containing element in your html so that you can test that test is next to test2 e.g. with

```
div#row
  span#info1  test
  span#info2  rest
```

You could write something with capybara like

```
expect(page).to have_css('#row info1', text: 'test')
expect(page).to have_css('#row info2', text: 'rest')
```

If you haven't got another identifiers, css classes or html in your source to do this that simply, you can either modify your source, or use more complex css/xpath queries (google 'css siblings')